# Replace content of header tag based on its own existing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

dI have a pre-existing block of html I need to alter using jQuery. The HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="wms-column wms-column-nav">
        <div class="wms-column-nav-body">
        <div class="section">
            <h3>Recent News</h3>
            <ul class="other">
            <li>Something</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

I need to target the H3 and change its inner text. However, with no IDs, targeting it with selectors is tricky. There are many other H3 tags through their site that cannot be changes, but have the same selector path. How can I target this H3 based on its content, and then change it? I'd prefer a method that inserts html and not text, as some special characters are going to be used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla Javascript :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
for (var i=elements.length; i-->0; ) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var text = element.textContent || element.innerText;
    if (text=='Recent News') {
       element.innerHTML = 'some new text';   
    }
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/TAuar/)

Comment: Looks good. Would this be a bit much in the case of a page having many, many H3 tags?

Comment: There would be no problem, as long as you don't do it every few milliscondes. I just changed to call length only one time if you're performance obsessed (this isn't an array but a dynamic collection so obtaining the length isn't exactly instantaneous. If you're sure you have only one element to change, you might break when it's found. But don't overoptimize : this is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

`$('h3')` will select all of the header tags. You can address them individually: `$('h3').eq(0)` `$('h3').eq(1)` etc.

You can also loop through them easily:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
     alert(this.text()) <-- "this" will point to the current item in the loop.
})
```

Inside the loop you can access any of the current item's content, properties or attributes. You can base your logic on this accordingly.